# Problems with FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

i'm adding programatically 3 textviews into a framelayout that haves a camera view.

The three textviews are writting in the same position, but i want to put each textview bottom to another (using framelayout)

I dont know how to do it, i can't find any examples or info about doing this with framelayout programatically, and also i didnt find the way to do it with setlayoutparams, because that method doesn't have x/y parameters or something like that.

here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       cv = new CustomCameraView(this.getApplicationContext());
       FrameLayout rl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
       setContentView(rl);
       rl.addView(cv);

       tv1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
       tv2=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
       tv3=new TextView(getApplicationContext());

       rl.addView(tv1);
       rl.addView(tv2);
       rl.addView(tv3);

       tv1.setText("Test1");
       tv2.setText("Test2");
       tv3.setText("Test3");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a linearLayout, add the textViews to this LinearLayout , and add this linearLayout to your FrameLayout.  Use the orientation of LinearLayout vertical.

use `LinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)`, method for setting orientation to vertical.

Comment: how to set orientation Vertical programatically?